# Display a html form to specific user in php and mysql

Tags: php, sql

I made a login system where a users will register a account once he register and login to his account he will be taken to protected page! and in  the protected page there is a small html form what I want to do is that I want to disable the form for those users who have already submitted it!

Instead of the form I want them to see a different message

Please help me to get this done!

Registration Page:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
    header("Location: home");
}
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
    $uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
    $lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
    $upass = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']));

    if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(username,email,fname,lname,password) VALUES('$uname','$email','$fname','$lname','$upass')"))
    {
        ?>
        <script>alert('Your New Account Has Been Registered!! Please Login Now ');</script>
<script>window.location.replace("login");</script>
       <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>alert('There was an error! Please make sure you have provided correct information');</script>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Login Page:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
    header("Location: home");
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);

    if($row['password']==md5($upass))
    {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
        header("Location: home");
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>alert('Invalid email or password');</script>
        <?php
    }

}
?>
```

Protected Page:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{

    header("Location: http://siteveo.com/login");
}

$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
?>
```

the application form is a php mail contact form

Comment: Can you show us what you have done already.

Comment: protected page                                                                                                        <?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{

 header("Location: http://siteveo.com/login");
}

$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
?>

Comment: Edited the post please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user registers, I am guessing that you create a new record for this user in your database. When the user logs in, your PHP script can query the database to check the user's name and password to see if a matching record exists. If MySQL returns no record, then you get PHP to echo your HTML form; if MySQL returns a record, then PHP does not echo the form.